# Check for Record counts against the loaded Data

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a CSV file to be loaded to the oledb destination using SSIS, I have also an info file about that CSV file which is stored as a .info file which contains the number of records of that specific CSV file (say 12786980). After the CSV file is loaded to the staging table I want to do validation by checking if all records have been loaded (cross check with the info file), if equal go to the next task (which is another transformation to the loaded data) else break it and send an error email.
Source (csv file(actual data) and info file(contains number of records for that csv file)).
I tried with record counts on the loaded data from the staging table but stuck on how to read the info file (which is a single numeric row) to verify whether all data is loaded. Any help!

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question more?

Comment: Here's one way to load a single value out of a file into a variable.. although usually I think script task is overkill, this might be the easiest way to do it https://svangasql.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/how-to-read-a-flat-file-to-variable-ssis-script-task/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read data from a .info file in the same way as from a .txt file. You can then assign this value to a variable and compare it to the count in the staging table.

[image]